# Url automatically being escaped and not routed

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm having this issue where the Url after the # is being escaped and angularJS is not routing correctly. It looks like this in the navigation bar on chrome:

[image: #/test]

I'm using GAE python and angular for the frontend. In the inspector view the Urls appear unescaped:

[image: unescaped URL]

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few hours here. Is there a setting for GAE that is doing this automatically or something I missed in angular?

Comment: why do you need the # there?

Comment: That's how angular differentiates its routes from the server's: [ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

Comment: use `ng-href="/login"` rather than href with #

Comment: @entre that won't make any difference

Comment: The URL does look wrong. Note the URL you end up with #%2F.  So the problem is with the Angular side of things and not appengine, given the information provided.

Comment: are the urls equivalent in this case?

Comment: What are you using on the Python side of things to send (what you wish were) `<a href="#/login">` etc? Please edit your Q to show us the relevant snippet of server-side Python code.